# split UUID in group of 3 characters

Tags: java, string, split

I need to extract the first 9 characters of my UUID, and then split them into group of 3.

For integer id I am doing something like that

```
 String[] arr = String.format ("%09d", id).split("(?<=\\G.{3})");
```

Converting the integer id into 9 characters and then splitting it in the group of 3.

How to get the first 9 characters of UUID and then split it in groups of 3

Comment: So, is there anything going wrong?

Comment: I can't do the same for UUID string

Comment: can you give an example code where it doesn't work?

Comment: Hey @summu did you try my answer? Did it help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get first 9 characters of your String, you can try a code like this:

```java
String firstNineChars = s.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), 9));
```

And then just directly split the String, `firstNineChars` like this:

```java
String first = firstNineChars.substring(0,3);
String second = firstNineChars.substring(3,6);
String third = firstNineChars.substring(6,9);
```

Comment: Hey @PradymanDixit, I have posted my answer, You were right in the first part, as for grouping part I need to join it as group separated by '/'
Check my answer

Comment: @summu nice, do vote up the answer, or mark it as correct, if you think it can solve other person's problem, I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Comment: yea sure, upvote my question also so others find it useful

Answer (score 0):

For the standard Java UUID class, simply clean up the string of '-' characters and cut of the first 9 remaining characters.
Then you regex will work the same way.

If you want the first 9 characters from the left (first, the way humans read), use this code:

```
String [] arr = id.toString().replaceAll("-", "").substring(0, 9).split("(?<=\\G.{3})");
```

If you want the first 9 from the right (representing LSB), you will need an extra step:

```
String str = id.toString().replaceAll("-", "");
String [] arr = str.substring(str.lenght() - 9).split("(?<=\\G.{3})");
```

Answer (score 0):

UUID has format `1957afac-f1c2-4da7-9151-249a3fa742be`, so the first group is `1957afac`. And you want to get is with group of 3: `[195, 7af, ac]`.

You can treat it as simple string with known reguired number positions, so you do not need to find a first `-` to split a first group:

```
public static String[] getFirstGroup(String uuid) {
    return new String[] { uuid.substring(0, 3), uuid.substring(3, 6), uuid.substring(6, 8) };
}

public static String[] getFirstGroup(UUID uuid) {
    return getFirstGroup(uuid.toString());
}
```

In case you need e.g. 2nd group, then obvious way is to find '-' and find a substring. But if you look at `UUID.toString()`:

```
public String toString() {
    return (digits(mostSigBits >> 32, 8) + "-" +
            digits(mostSigBits >> 16, 4) + "-" +
            digits(mostSigBits, 4) + "-" +
            digits(leastSigBits >> 48, 4) + "-" +
            digits(leastSigBits, 12));
}
```

you could see, that using `digits` method (this is `private static`, but you could copyt these one line method) you could easily find required group without parse a string.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
String itemID = item_id.toString();
String upToNCharacters[] = itemID.substring(0, Math.min(itemID.length(), 9)).split("(?<=\\G.{3})");;
String UUIDAsString = StringUtils.join(Arrays.asList(upToNCharacters),"/");
```